# a tag onclick function not executed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to execute a function  when tthe link is clicked  but it's not executed and I don't see an error on the console

```
<div class="item-link-div">
       <a onlick="myfunction('param1','param2','param3', window.location.href)" href="myurl" class="footer-top-list-item-link">
                ...

        </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is because you write **onlick** and not **onclick**

Answer (score 0):

`anchor` tag have both `onclick`(check you in your code) and `href`. So the click event will first execute and then `href`. In click handler use `e.preventDefault`. In this case the onclick will first execute then href

```js
function myfunction(e, p) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(window.location.href)
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-link-div">
  <a onclick="myfunction(event,param)" href="myurl" class="footer-top-list-item-link">
                {!! t("footer.layoutFooter_history") !!}
        </a>
</div>
```